# Why did A.M.A.Z.O. need to come to Earth?

Tags: dc, dc-animated-universe, justice-league

Why did A.M.A.Z.O. need to come to Earth for Lex Luthor? Why didn't it just teleport him to its location?

Answer (score 2):

There are many possible reasons for A.M.A.Z.O. to have returned to Earth as opposed to bringing Luthor to him (or just killing him from millions of miles away, with a bolt from the blue).  The show doesn't go into detail about his motivations, so for an in-universe answer we will have to use conjecture.  From an out-of-universe reason, Earth is where the plot was.  A.M.A.Z.O. couldn't bring Luthor to him or kill him from a distance because it would have sidestepped the plot.  We wouldn't have gotten to see him tear through the League, we wouldn't have gotten the philosophy, and the storyline would have been wrecked.

So, let's look at the potential in-universe reasons:

- **A.M.A.Z.O. couldn't bring Luthor to him**

Ivo's android is certainly powerful, but his powers have never really been demonstrated outside of visual range.  He can fly through space (at amazing velocity), ignore pretty much any damage thrown at him, shift planets into other dimensions, and deliver punches/laser blasts/etc that are absolutely devastating.  None of this, however, demonstrates his ability to effect things he cannot see or otherwise perceive.

The most likely answer is that A.M.A.Z.O. simply couldn't bring Luthor to him or kill him from a ludicrous range.

- **He wanted Luthor to know he was coming**

A.M.A.Z.O. was angry.  He didn't want to punish Luthor, he wanted revenge.  It wouldn't have been enough for him to simply KILL Luthor, he wanted Luthor to be afraid.  What better way than battering his way dramatically through every defense Luthor could construct?

- **He wanted to test himself**

Near-infinite, cosmic power is hard to quantify.  The android hadn't had a challenge in a long time.  Getting to Luthor the hard way gave him a chance to practice, to test himself against the best heroes in the Universe.  It also had side-benefits - he got to make Luthor sweat.

- **Frequent Flier Miles**

You can't discount the sheer number of miles A.M.A.Z.O. racked up on his journey back to Earth.  Just three more of those trips, and he can go to Hawaii *FREE*.

All joking aside, Ivo's android almost certainly returned to Earth for his vengeance due to some combination of the first and second point.  Once he arrived at Earth, his rationale for his actions was obvious: he wanted to kill Luthor *and no one else*.  He disabled most of the League, but was unwilling to use lethal force unless he could be certain only Luthor would suffer from it.

Comment: `his powers have never really been demonstrated outside of visual range.` ~> In the end A.M.A.Z.O. restored Oa which was outside of its visual range.

Comment: True, I had forgotten that part.  That said, undoing something you've recently done is probably not difficult, especially if you knew you might have to do it, and set it up so you could do it quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Amazo was designed to evolve but he didn't know why or what he was supposed to be evolving into. He also returned to earth because he had a vendetta against Lex because Lex was just using him to destroy the JL
And Lex also tried to kill Amazo by using the kill switch (a bomb that Ivo put in his neck.)
So, Amazo didn't just teleport Lex to himself because it's more dramatic and interesting to wipe out the JL first and Amazo was really just confused about his purpose in life and somehow he knew that Lex would have the answer otherwise he would have just killed Lex immediately.
Lex told him that he must make his own purpose and thus enlightened he stopped his attack on Lex.

Comment: Why the down vote? Some constructive feedback would be nice...

Comment: I didn't DV, but this part catches my attention "So, Amazo didn't just teleport Lex to himself because it's more dramatic and interesting to wipe out the JL first" - is this an out-of-universe answer, or is that supported in-universe by something someone said or did?

Comment: This answer reads more as a stream of consiousness than a well-thought response.  It answers the question with an offhand remark in the middle, which isn't built up to by the initial paragraph, and doesn't provide any support for the answer given.  It also fails to establish motivation for Amazo to want to defeat the league.  In short, your answer was downvoted (not by me) because it is a poor answer, and not delivered well.  Clean up the grammar, establish the motives for Amazo, and cite your sources.  You'll see a much improved reaction.